# System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, federated-identity, claims

I am using BrockAllen.MembershipReboot

Having an issue with the claims handling in relation to when exactly the claims get updated.  The code below should demonstrate my problem...

```
private function UpdateGender(string newGender)
{
    account.RemoveClaim(ClaimTypes.Gender);
    account.AddClaim(ClaimTypes.Gender, newGender);
    userAccountService.Update(account);

    // since we've changed the claims, we need to re-issue the cookie that
    // contains the claims.
    authSvc.SignIn(User.Identity.Name);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult function myAjaxMethod(){
    UpdateGender("male");

    string gender = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.GetValue(ClaimTypes.Gender);

    // the "gender" variable will never be "male" in this request (unless it was already male)
    // because although we've set the cookie it hasn't updated the claim until the next request 
    // when it reads the cookie again.
    return Json(gender);
}
```

My question is this:

Is there a way to force the `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.GetValue()` method to update it's claims at the point where the cookie is issued?

Comment: You have to reissue the cookie.

Comment: Yes.. I know. But what about other code that executes in the same request as the claim update?  How do I access the (now updated) claim data?  By the time this code has been executed the cookie has been re-set on the header but the response has not yet been sent back to the client.

Comment: Then recreate the `ClaimsIdentity` on `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` from where the `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` reads the current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` accesses the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` locally, I guess you could just update the current thread principal for the lifetime of the current request.

```
  // your existing code
  account.RemoveClaim(ClaimTypes.Gender);
  account.AddClaim(ClaimTypes.Gender, newGender);

  // additional code that updates current thread principal 
  ClaimsPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
  if ( principal != null ) {

      ClaimsIdentity identity = principal.Identities.ElementAt(0);
      identity.AddClaim( new Claim( ClaimTypes.Gender, "asdf" ) );
  }

  // this works now
  string gender = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.GetValue( ClaimTypes.Gender );
```

Note that since you are reissuing the cookie, the next request should correctly pick up your changes.

Comment: How do I reissue the cookie?

Comment: @DurgaPrasad: http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/09/forms-authentication-revisited.html